# Completely lost. Program parses html 100% fine locally, but fails when run from App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've coded up a little utility scraper that will show me some info each day. This runs 100% without fail, no issues at all when run locally. It opens the connections, creates the BeautifulSoup objects, scrapes its content, and prints everything to the screen. All is well.

However, when I run the same code on App Engine, I suddenly get a parse error for some reason!

The code is as straight forward as it gets.

```
    url = 'MY_URL'
    agent = ('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 '
        '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31')

    headers = {'User-Agent' : agent}

    data = urllib.urlencode(form_data)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    return urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

So, this opens up the page. I then take this page, and parse it with `BeautifulSoup`

```
page = get_page()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

That's it. Like I said, runs fine. I've run this script 100s of times locally without issue. Now, I thought I'd stick it on App Engine. I thought the `urllib` requests would be an issue, but it turns out that place the code is failing is in the `BeautifulSoup` call.

AppEngines's log shows the error:

```
soups = [BeautifulSoup(response) for response in responses]
  File "libs\bs4\__init__.py", line 172, in __init__
    self._feed()
  File "libs\bs4\__init__.py", line 185, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(self.markup)
  File "libs\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 150, in feed
    raise e
HTMLParseError: expected name token at u'<! /notices/notice.c', at line 51, column 3
```

I've verified that I'm getting the correct pages when the requests are made from AppEngine. So... I'm completely lost. Why is there suddenly a parse issue?

Comment: Are you parsing the same things locally as on App Engine?  Because that doesn't look like valid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the notes on BeautifulSoup about [installing a parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).  BeautifulSoup uses a third party parser, choosing from whatever happens to be installed on your system, with `lxml` given the highest priority.

Each parser has it strengths/weaknesses, some are more lenient than others.  It's likely that you have a different set of parsers installed on your local system than your AppEngine work area, and a less lenient parser is being used on AppEngine.

Refer to the code at the bottom of BeautifulSoup source `bs4/builder/__init__.py` for a current list of supported parsers and their precedence.

Comment: Ah, that took care of it. It parsed with no problem once I installed `lxml`. Thanks!!